# web app with play framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

I downloaded play 2.0, extracted the file to location, C:\play-2.0 and added the classpath.
Its gives below error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVers­ionError: Bad version n
umber in .class file
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Java version is too old to work with Play framework. You can check your java version by running

`java -version`

You need at least Java 1.6, which you can download from here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6downloads-1902814.html